# finding sum of digits after decimal in a float till arbitary precision

Tags: python, python-2.7, sum, decimal, modulus

I am trying to find the sum of 2000 decimal digits of a number created by a fraction, `a/b`. I am getting a lot of the digits until i hit `NaN` (not a number). I hit NaN when the loop runs around 310 times. How do I get the rest of the digits?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import math
a = 3.00
b = 857.00
c = a/b
result = 0.0
s = 0.0
for x in range(0, 2000 , 1):
    s= c % 10
    result += int(s)
    c *= 10

print result
```

Comment: Two remarks: `import math` is not needed, as you don't use any functions from the `math` module. And `range(0, 2000, 1)` can be simplified to `range(2000)`.

Comment: Any particluar reason why you can't use the [`Decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)?

Comment: becouse i have an assignment where decimal module is not allowed

Comment: c is going to infinity which results in s becoming a NaN because you are effectively multiplying aba/b by 10^310. You are trying to deal with 2000 digit decimals and that can't be done using a native data type

Comment: ahhh, how do i remove the integers then?

Comment: Another remark: Don't initialize `s` as a floating point number (`0.0`). Use an integer (`0`) instead, it has unlimited size in Python and you are accumulating integers only anyway.

Comment: Your problem statement is unclear. Are you trying to sum the *digits* of a/b?

Comment: im trying to sum all the decimals of a number that is produced by a/b. if the number was 0.2847 i would sum (2+8+4+7)

Comment: is there any other way to sum the decimals, than how my code do it?

Comment: You will run into many problems with floating point and rounding in this approach because the `c *= 10` will keep bringing in extra digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong approach. Using a direct float division limits your ability to calculate the decimals, because integers can be converted to floats based on the underlying libraries, as [mentioned in documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float), and by default float would not save numbers to arbitrary precision (2000 in your case):

> When passing in a string, values for NaN and Infinity may be returned, depending on the underlying C library. Float accepts the strings nan, inf and -inf for NaN and positive or negative infinity. The case and a leading + are ignored as well as a leading - is ignored for NaN. Float always represents NaN and infinity as nan, inf or -inf.

In your case (as also in mine), that limit happens to be `2**1024`. Go to your python prompt, and try running the following:

```
>>> float(2**1024)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float
>>> float(2**1023)
8.98846567431158e+307
```

The above number basically corresponds to the value that `c` would have had in your code above, in the end of the 310th iteration, and given that c is defined as float, it would throw the error.

Basically, this means that any ***`float`*** number equal to or bigger than `2 **1024` will be converted to `nan` or `inf`, and hence your existing code won't run.

Also, note that [floating point calculations have limitations anyway](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), so your answer would not have been correct for such high precision.

So instead, I suggest you  calculate the remainder in each turn on dividing by the denominator, b, as used in the following:

```
a = 3
b = 857
result = 0
if a:
    for x in range(0, 2000 , 1):
        a = a*10
        result += a / b
        a = a%b    

>>> print result
9056
```

Comment: This hits exactly what I was suggesting above because the floating point representation keeps bringing in spurious digits

Comment: @kdopen When I initially read the question, for a few moments, I wasn't able to figure out why the nan's would appear given that python supports arbitarily large ints. Then I read the docs, and realized this was a limitation with the floats :)

Comment: Yep, but the 'correct' anser for his values of a and b is `43`. Yours got `9056`, my floating approach got `189`. That's why I said to go with a string approach

Comment: @kdopen Are you serious? He is looking for sum of 2000 digits after the decimal, and the sum is ***only*** 189? FWIW, your solution goes upto some 10 or 20 digits after the decimal. Using floating point in any way is simply not the answer.

Comment: thanks man this worked perfectly! i guess i was on the right track but i dont yet totally understand why i got NaN in for my previus code

Comment: I suggest using `a // b` in place of `a / b`, to make it clear that it's a floor division (and so that the code works under Python 3).